# Should JSON data override JSON schema? (Using schema and data with jdorn/json-editor)

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I've created JSON data from a schema using json-editor's forms. Later, I've modified the schema, adding a few fields. My expectation was that the new fields would be displayed with null or default data. What surprised me is that the new fields that don't appear in the data are not displayed.

For instance, in this example, check out the "Video Loop" field in the schema that doesn't appear in the Shot object because it wasn't originally in the JSON data.

[JSON Editor Example with Data](http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/?schema=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&value=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&theme=bootstrap3&iconlib=bootstrap3&object_layout=normal&show_errors=interaction&required_by_default)

Is this expected behavior? Is there a workaround for this? Is there a way the form can amend the incoming data?

Answer (score 0):

The URL goes directly to jdorn's json-editor example which allows you to input schema and generate a form and then with the form generate JSON data. Or from JSON data you can have it populate the form. I think the "save form to URL" button on the example encodes all of the data in the URL, so the URL might get truncated and not work. Here it is if you haven't used it: http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/

I was using the form on my own site tonight and happily it doesn't do what I reported the example did. If the data doesn't contain fields in the schema/form it just assigns them the defaults. In fact, if the data contains fields not in the form, it adds new fields to the form.

So this allows you to modify a schema/form without rendering your data worthless. In fact, you can populate the form with your data and rewrite it and get data consistent with the form.

So we can consider this resolved.